# Is it possible to use the Microsoft face tracking SDK with a local image

Tags: face-detection, kinect-sdk

I was wondering if it was possible to get the 121 face's coordinates given by the Kinect Face Tracking SDK, but from a local image.
I mean, I have some local images on hard disk and I want to extract those points. 
Is this possible, or the face tracking algorithm only works with data provided by the Kinect Camera? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm used in the Microsoft Kinect FraceTracking example uses multiple points of data that come directly from the Kinect sensor -- the depth data being the primary point that you will be lacking.  As a result, it is not possible to simply plug an image into the algorithm to obtain the data points from the flat image.

There are multiple examples around the web to extract facial features from both flat images as well as standard video (i.e., no depth data included).  Some standard image processing libraries (e.g., OpenCV) may even include them already baked in (though I can't confirm this).